# Выравнивание HR по li навигации

Tags: html, css

Есть следующий код:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">Home</a></li>
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">About me</a></li>
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">Skills</a></li>
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть макет:
[image: Header]

Не могу сделать так, чтобы пункты навигации были одинаковых размеров с `<hr>`. Получается, что если позиционировать навигацию посередине, то линия будет слева и справа выпирать. На гридах тоже не вышло ничего. Я так понимаю, что нужно первый элемент позиционировать к левому краю, последний к последнему, а между основными элементами рассчитывать расстояние? По макету отступы 155 px между элементами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем использовать `<hr>`?
Почему бы не использовать `border-bottom`?

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

.list_item a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">Home</a></li>
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">About me</a></li>
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">Skills</a></li>
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="list_item"><a href="" class="link_item">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное). 2й день мучений идет, но с опытом начну уже мыслить иначе, надеюсь.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Если мой ответ вам помог - отметьте его как правильный (галочка под рейтингом, слева от ответа).

Comment: Да, я отметил. Публично не меняется, так как репутация меньше 15.